# mapping data in properties files

Tags: java, data-structures, properties

I have the following data:

```
User   System    SubSystem
user1  System1   SubSystem1
user2  System1   SubSystem2
user3  N/A       N/A
```

and i need to be able to determine the system/subsystem tuple from the user. I must be able to add users at any time without rebuilding and redeploying the system.

I know the database would be the best option here but **I cannot use a database table.**

I currently have it mapped using a hash map but I don't want it to be hard-coded. I was thinking about using a properties file but I can't visualize how I would implement it. Anyone else have any suggestion?

Not that it matters but I'm using JAVA, on weblogic 10.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go for something as simple as :

```
user1 = userValue
user1.system = systemValue
user1.system.subsystem= subsystemValue
user2 = userValue
user2.system = systemValue
user2.system.subsystem= subsystemValue
```

user(id) is used as "primary" key in your properties, and a very simple concatenation of your fields to store your table values.
I use this very often : trust me, it's much more powerfull than it may appear :)

Comment: i was thinking of a solution in this area, with some little changes to make sure the properties dont go threading into other domains it could be the way i will be going.

Comment: Log4J does something similar as well

Answer (score 3):

You could do this using a HashMap (as you do now) and store it using [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/).

XStream allows you to serialise/deserialise Java objects to/from readable/editable XML. You can then write this to (say) a filesystem, and the result is editable by hand.

The downside is that it's a serialisation in XML of a Java object, so not as immediately obvious as a properties file to edit. However it's still very readable, and easily understood by anyone remotely technical. Whether this is an appropriate solution depends on the audience of this file.

Comment: storing it in the fylesystem? will the result be editable by hand?

Comment: Yes. Edited above for clarification

Comment: you just gave me the solution for a future project ;) +1

Comment: Excellent! Glad to be of help

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like something you could very well use [YAML](http://www.yaml.org/) for..
[SnakeYAML](http://trac-hg.assembla.com/snakeyaml/wiki/Documentation) looks to be a workable Java implementation.

Answer (score 0):

For this project i've gone with the solution proposed by Olivier. Some project contrainst (legacy of the project) prevent me for going with a probably better solution of using XStream.

Thx for the feed back guys